# Python DataFrame Column to a comma separated value string

Tags: python, pandas

First I have searched Stakeoverflow and googled

but I got was how to join columns with comma for the same record or how to convert CSV to dataframe

My Dataset looks like this

```
ID     Name
1      Tom
2      John
3      Mike
4      Nancy
```

I want to get a string that has all Names with comma in between them

```
st = "Tom,John,Mike,Nancy"
```

I tried this code but doesn't give me the results I expected

```
st = df["Name"].to_string()
```

How can I do that

Comment: `df['Name'].str.cat(sep=',')`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
st = ','.join(df["Name"])
```

Comment: oh it's good than my code cause won't have to turn to list :D 
cool man!

Comment: Do note, that @Robert Price's solution is brittle.

Answer (score 2):

```
df[my_columns].tolist()
```

will be transform pd.Series to list python

and then using normal python to join list to string

```
','.join(df[my_columns].tolist())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
var_name = ','.join(df["Name"])
```

Answer (score 1):

df['Name'] is a Series. These objects have a [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_csv.html) method. Essentially, you'll do something akin to:

```
out = df['Name'].to_csv(path_of_buf=None, header=False, index=False)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this will output as a column

Answer (score 1):

You could either look into listagg on a df field. This [link](https://medium.com/@oliviercruchant/python-pandas-listagg-udf-e1429a972995) should provide you with a snippet that can help.

Or simply join a string of comma to the series itself...

```
','.join(dataframe['column'].tolist())
```

or

```
dataframe['column'].to_csv(header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

For single column you can use:

```
"'"+DataFram.Column.map(lambda x: 
x.strip()).to_string(index=False).replace('\n',"','")+"'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe column that you want to get a comma separated string out of contains numbers, you might want to first map the cells to string like so:

`st = ','.join(map(str, df["Col1"]))`